# Disabling 10k checkboxes in IE11 takes 1 minute but 1 second in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I am trying to disable 10k check boxes in a grid. Iterating in for loop and getting the id of the check box and disabling. IE11 takes almost 1 minute but chrome takes just 1 second. Any way to improve in IE.

```
function DisableCheckboxes() {
    $("#divGrid").find("input[type='checkbox']").removeAttr("disabled").prop("checked", false).closest("td").css("background-color", "transparent");

    var nodes = $(".nodeElement");
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        var nodeName = $(nodes[i]).attr('name');
        $("#" + nodeName).attr("disabled", "disabled").closest("td").css("background-color", "#E7E7E7");
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: It might be useful to add the code you're using

Comment: if you are doing get elementbyId 10k times that might be why, it could be better to get the parent element and loop through the children, that way you're not forcing IE to do a lookup on the dom every time

Comment: Added code. It is not always 10k , it can vary from 1  to 10k max.if an element present in tree am disabling that  in grid

Comment: Can you reduce the number of function calls in the loop by changing `$(nodes[i]).attr('name')` to `nodes[i].name`? And avoid an assignment on every iteration by getting rid of the `nodeName` variable and just using the value directly on the next line? (You don't really need any variable that is only used once after its value is assigned.)

Comment: @nnnnnn that is not avoidable

Comment: Yes it is. Change `$("#" + nodeName)` to `$("#" + nodes[i].name)` and you don't need the extra variable and assignment.

Comment: Would you also add the HTML markup? `closest()` might be the biggest performance concern.

Comment: @Pavlo you are right , removed that and used hide() and show() it also improved